# vclick event to click event in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a load of code that originally was used in a jquery mobile app. 
I'd like to port some of the code to another project but keep the 'vclick' binding code in place.
Is there a way to delegate all 'vclick' events to click events?

any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

vclick is a jQuery Mobile event. So if you still use jQueryMobile, I don't see what is your problem. If you need to use the old code without changing vclick event to click event, you can trigger a vclick event when a click event occurs, but it's not nice at all ! A quick find and replace in your code is better.

Comment: pretty much that what I was thinking, but thought there might be an easy way to do it so I could use the same code in different view frameworks. thanks.

Comment: update: that's what I did - still interested in way to possibly achieve it though. thanks